# How to show count in heatmap instead of magnitude?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I am trying to implement an openlayers heatmap example below:

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html

Instead of magnitude is it possible to show count (how many points are in the same area)?

Edited:
pointer count and show when zoom out:
[image: pointer count and show when zoom out]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean showing clustered features as a heatmap, it can be done.  This is a combination of the Clustered Features example and the Heatmap example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Clustered Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <form>
      <label>cluster distance</label>
      <input id="distance" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="40"/>
      <label>radius size</label>
      <input id="radius" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="5"/>
      <label>blur size</label>
      <input id="blur" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="15"/>
    </form>
    <script>
      var distance = document.getElementById('distance');
      var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
      var radius = document.getElementById('radius');

      var count = 20000;
      var features = new Array(count);
      var e = 4500000;
      for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
        features[i] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
      }

      var source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
      });

      var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: parseInt(distance.value, 10),
        source: source
      });

      var styleCache = {};
      var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
        source: clusterSource,
        weight: function(feature) { return feature.get('features').length/1000; },
        blur: parseInt(blur.value, 10),
        radius: parseInt(radius.value, 10)
      });

      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

      distance.addEventListener('input', function() {
        clusterSource.setDistance(parseInt(distance.value, 10));
      });

      blur.addEventListener('input', function() {
        vector.setBlur(parseInt(blur.value, 10));
      });

      radius.addEventListener('input', function() {
        vector.setRadius(parseInt(radius.value, 10));
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This version shows a normal cluster layer at zoom levels 0, 1 and 2 and a heatmap at zoom levels 3 or more

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Clustered Features</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <form>
      <label>cluster distance</label>
      <input id="distance" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="60"/>
      <label>radius size</label>
      <input id="radius" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="40"/>
      <label>blur size</label>
      <input id="blur" type="range" min="1" max="50" step="1" value="15"/>
    </form>
    <script>
      var distance = document.getElementById('distance');
      var blur = document.getElementById('blur');
      var radius = document.getElementById('radius');

      var count = 20000;
      var features = new Array(count);
      var e = 4500000;
      for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e];
        features[i] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates));
      }

      var source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: features
      });

      var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: parseInt(distance.value, 10),
        source: source
      });

      var styleCache = {};
      var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: clusterSource,
        style: function(feature) {
          var size = feature.get('features').length;
          var style = styleCache[size];
          if (!style) {
            style = new ol.style.Style({
              image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 15,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                  color: '#fff'
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                  color: '#3399CC'
                })
              }),
              text: new ol.style.Text({
                text: size.toString(),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                  color: '#fff'
                })
              })
            });
            styleCache[size] = style;
          }
          return style;
        },
        minResolution: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ().getResolution(3) + 1
      });

      var vector = new ol.layer.Heatmap({
        source: clusterSource,
        weight: function(feature) { return feature.get('features').length/500; },
        blur: parseInt(blur.value, 10),
        radius: parseInt(radius.value, 10),
        maxResolution: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ().getResolution(3) + 1
      });

      var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });

      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [raster, clusters, vector],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 3
        })
      });

      distance.addEventListener('input', function() {
        clusterSource.setDistance(parseInt(distance.value, 10));
      });

      blur.addEventListener('input', function() {
        vector.setBlur(parseInt(blur.value, 10));
      });

      radius.addEventListener('input', function() {
        vector.setRadius(parseInt(radius.value, 10));
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you data is random you could find the current largest cluster size and use that when dividing to calculate the weight:

```
    weight: function(feature) { 
       var maxSize = 0;
       clusterSource.forEachFeature( function(feature) { maxSize = Math.max(maxSize, feature.get('features').length); } );
       return feature.get('features').length/maxSize;
    },
```

Comment: Hi @Mike, thank you so much for your reply. I am using clustered features same as your example but want to show points counter in the same area when zoom out, I have added an image as an example.Please check my edited portion.

Comment: You would need two layers using clusterSource, a heatmap as above and a normal vector layer with a style function as in the openlayers example for clustered features.  Specify a maxResolution in the heatmap options and the same value as minResolution for the other layer.

Comment: Could you please update your code to reflect the same as you are saying, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I have implemented your code but when I add minResolution for cluster layer and maxResolution for heatmap layer only heatmap layer works not the clusters layer with count style, but when I remove minResolution from clusters then the count down style works but the heatmap doesn't work, what could be the reason of happening such thing?

Comment: I have found the problem I have view set such way: center: 
            maxZoom: 19,
            zoom: 8,
            minZoom: 3, and I also need these value set so what need to do in this case?

Comment: Hi @Mike, if you browse this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/heatmap-earthquakes.html and zoom in each point with blue color, is it possible to do the same using your code?

Comment: Weight has to be between 0 and 1.  The the OL example they subtract 5 from the quake magnitude so 5.1 is always 0.1 weight.  In my examples I have divided cluser size by 500 or 1000 because the biggest clusters were about that size but when you zoom in the clusters reduce to 1 so the weight will only be 0.001 or 0.002.  There's no reason why you couldn't replace the dividing number with something configurable or one calculated based on zoom level or resolution.

Comment: Hi @Mike, in my case the size of points come randomly depending on search criteria  so I don't know by which number I can divide. I have used for weight here: weight: function(feature) { return feature.get('features').length/2; }